# django handwritten migrations altering auth

Tags: django, database-migration, django-migrations

I am using django 1.8.1 and trying to extend the length of auth_user name field from one of my apps. Before, with south, I could just target the app with an underscore like so:

```
db.alter_column('auth_group', 'name', models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, blank=False))
```

However, in django 1.8, I don't see a way to do this as django putts the app name in the sql withing the source code. I don't want to edit django source code so I have no way of changing that. my current attemp is here:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002'),
]       

operations = [
    migrations.AlterField('auth_group', 'name', field=models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False, blank=False)),
]
```

Please help. I don't want to edit django source code and I only want to do migrations.RunSQL as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a tricky way to do that:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db.migrations import Migration as DjangoMigration, AlterField
from django.db.models import CharField


class Migration(DjangoMigration):
    dependencies = [
        # Specify other dependencies, if required.
        ('auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002')
    ]
    operations = [
        AlterField(
            model_name='User',
            name='username',
            field=CharField(max_length=120)
        )
    ]

    def mutate_state(self, project_state, preserve=True):
        """
        This is a workaround that allows to store ``auth``
        migration outside the directory it should be stored.
        """
        app_label = self.app_label
        self.app_label = 'auth'
        state = super(Migration, self).mutate_state(project_state, preserve)
        self.app_label = app_label
        return state

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        """
        Same workaround as described in ``mutate_state`` method.
        """
        app_label = self.app_label
        self.app_label = 'auth'
        state = super(Migration, self).apply(project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql)
        self.app_label = app_label
        return state
```

Put this in your application's `migrations` folder with a proper name, e.g. `0001_alter_auth_user_username.py`.

I'm not sure, however, that this is a good approach.

Comment: So in essence, I'm changing the app name for that entire migration class?

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick You are changing it in certain places so migration can obtain model from the right application, i.e. `User` model will be obtained from `auth` application meanwhile migration itself will belong to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ernest Ten.

In my case, I kept the dependency on: 
    `dependencies = [
       # Specify other dependencies, if required.
        ('auth', '0004_alter_user_username_opts')
    ]`

Make sure you run "python manage.py migrate" to get this reflected to you db.