# How to extend username field length in Django 1.7.8?

Tags: python, django, authentication

Current Django username length limit is 30 characters.

My Profile model looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
....
```

Is there are any not so ugly solution as this [What is the 'right' way to extend the username field length in Django 1.5+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136282/what-is-the-right-way-to-extend-the-username-field-length-in-django-1-5)

P.S.
It is already deployed and there are hundreds of users. I can't just implement my own user class based on abstract user. I need some "hack". Currently I changed value directly in Django for my local clone, but is is even more ugly, that monkey patching.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using ?

Comment: This question may help: [django handwritten migrations altering auth](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31385503/5098707).